# Using my R GUI in C# application

Tags: c#, r

I have a complex and well established C# application, from which I will extract data for processing in R. I will then need to feedback the analytics calculated in R into C#. This is to ensure that the end-user is provided a holistic experience.

However, I would also like to use the charting and graphics functionality of R within the C# application because C# graphics aren't the best.

Is there a known solution to this type of hybrid application?

Comment: There are plenty of good charting options for .net.

Comment: Have you tried R.NET (to communicate between C# with R)? It has experimental feature for graphics. Anyway, I would suggest to use .NET charts (there are plenty of components on the Internet).

Comment: I did try R.NET, but it seems a little buggy. As for good charting libraries for .NET, I haven't found anything that's good quality and open source. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential solutions I've tried include saving the R chart as a stand alone file and serving that image to the C# application. However, this isn't a very nice approach in part because the charts are not interactive. I've tried to overlay some fake interactivity but this is a bit of a shoddy work-around.

Instead, the best approach I've come up with that really gives a nice wide range of solutions is to simple perform the data processing in R, and use an SVG viewer in the C# application.

R Shiny, R Charts, and (NV)D3 etc. can go some way to providing a nice overall solution.